# Define a list of variables in ant, that can be used in a for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, ant

I'm writing an ant build file for a project with a couple of dependencies. I'm required to write a separate file that contains targets common to all projects, and then write the project-specific stuff in their own buildfiles. For instance,  I have a target called "cleanDependencies".

```
<target name="cleanDependencies">
    <echo>Cleaning dependencies... </echo>
    <for list="dep1,dep2" param="dependency">
          <sequential>
                <ant dir="dep/@{dependency}" target="clean" inheritAll="false" />
          </sequential>
    </for>      
</target>
```

This is a common target to all my projects, and I want to separate it into a common file of targets; something along the lines of

```
<target name="cleanDependencies">
    <echo>Cleaning dependencies... </echo>
    <for list="${listOfDependencies}" param="dependency">
          <sequential>
                <ant dir="dep/@{dependency}" target="clean" inheritAll="false" />
          </sequential>
    </for>      
</target>
```

Then, I can define a list in my project's buildfile called "listOfDependencies" and I can include the common target "cleanDependencies" from a different file, along these lines.

```
<list name="listOfDependencies"> <!-- Not a valid tag in Ant -->
    <item>dep1</item>
    <item>dep2</item>
</list>
```

My questions are:

1) Is there a way to define a list of variables in ant? This question is the same as another question ([Define a list or a set of variables in ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030190/define-a-list-or-a-set-of-variables-in-ant)) but the answers do not give a way of defining a list outside of the for loop.

2) Is there an alternate way of achieving this? i.e. a way to collect common targets in a separate file and then include it in the project-specific buildfile with appropriate variables.

Comment: The "for" task is not part of standard ant, which might explain some of your problems. For dependency management could I suggest looking at Apache ivy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `list` element or task in Ant. You can use a property containing the dependencies as comma-separated. The common target already relies on a `listOfDependencies` property, so all you need to do is pass that from the calling target. Should be as simple as:

```
<!-- calling buildfile -->
<property name="listOfDependencies" value="dep1,dep2" />
<ant antfile="common/build.xml" target="cleanDependencies" />
```

The subproject by default inherits all properties from the parent project (this can be controlled using the `inheritAll` attribute).

As for alternatives, take a look at the [`import`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/import.html) task which can be used to include the common buildfile and call it as if its targets are defined in the main buildfile.