# Define two param in for loop in ant script

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I am working on ant script and I am defining two param but script says you have already defined the param.Can yopu define how could I define two param in for loop in ant script.

```
    <project name="tomcat_win_deploy" basedir="." default="usage">
        <!--taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/-->
        <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

      <target name="env.copy.local.props">
        <for param="host" list="${deploy.host}" param="path" list="${deploy.path}">
          <sequential>
            <copy todir="\\@{host}\${deploy.path}\conf\"
                  file="Properties/${deploy.env}/local_for_test.properties"
                  overwrite="true"/>
          </sequential>
        </for>

  </target>
 </project>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way might be to define a list of delimited property pairs and process that in a loop, splitting each property into its two values.

So instead of having separate host and path lists:

```
hosts=a,b,c
paths=/a/,/b/,/c/
```

you might have a single host_path list:

```
host_path=a /a/, b /b/, c /c/
```

The trick then would be how to split variables and use them in the loop (and not running into the ant "properties are immutable" feature).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379052/127035) shows how you could use the Ant Flaka addon to achieve exactly that.